# My colormap diverges from zero but how can I move it to the center of the colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am working on some code to analyze a dataset and now am plotting it. My problem is that although I've added a midpoint so that the data diverges from zero (at white) it is not in the center of the colorbar.

```
def mapping(data):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
    lons, lats = data.getLongitude()[:], data.getLatitude()[:]
    data_mean = cdutil.averager(data,axis='0') 
    data_c, lon_c = add_cyclic_point((data_mean), coord=lons)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
    im=ax.contourf(lon_c, lats, data_c, 175,    
    vmin=np.min(data_mean),vmax=np.max(data_mean), norm = \
    MidpointNormalize(np.min(data_mean), np.max(data_mean),0. ), \
    cmap='PuOr', extend='both', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.coastlines()
    return plt.show()
```

Here is the map I get, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkAaD.jpg, as it shows the zero is at the white color but is not in the center of the colorbar which I would prefer.

Comment: If zero is supposed to be the center of the colorbar, you do not need to use `MidpointNormalize` - that is used if zero is to be off-center. Your problem seems rather that you do not specify any contour `levels` at all, hence they are automatically chosen.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see, I would like to use that but I'm not sure how I would specify them for each data that I pass through my function as they all require different levels.

Comment: Most probably you want to define `levels` programatically based on the input data. If you are looking for an answer with code, you may find it beneficial to supply a [mcve], which people can adapt.

Comment: You do not want 0 to be in the centre of the colorbar. If 0 is in the centre, you will, either way, get a different scale for positive and negative numbers (if you keep the bounds the way they are), or you will get a lot of wasted space in the colorbar as you will adapt the bounds to make them symmetric around zero. I highly doubt you want any of those two solutions, and I think you managed the most important here by putting 0 at the centre of the colormap. The only viable thing you could do would be to saturate the colorbar at the bottom, but you may not want that.